# rails 4 select with selected option not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my rails 4 form,  I have one field to select values.

```
<%= f.select(:owner_user_id, Item.find(session[:login_users_item_id]).try(:users).order_by_fullname.collect {|u| [ u.full_name, u.id ] } , {:selected =>  current_user.full_name} )%>
```

But, the above **selected** option not showing the above value. In console that value is getting properly.Now,The first item is showing in the select box.

How can I get the value in the selected option as the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.select(:owner_user_id, Item.find(session[:login_users_item_id]).try(:users).order_by_fullname.collect {|u| [ u.full_name, u.id ] }, selected: f.object.owner_user_id)%>
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks @ROR Developer

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to `f.select` method is the selected value, and there you can pass the value that you would like to see selected. In your case: `current_user.full_name`

```
<%= f.select(:owner_user_id, Item.find(session[:login_users_item_id]).try(:users).order_by_fullname.collect {|u| [ u.full_name, u.id ] }, current_user.full_name)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) helper.

**Example :**

```
<%= f.select :owner_user_id, options_for_select(Item.find(session[:login_users_item_id]).try(:users).order_by_fullname.pluck([ :full_name, :id ]), f.object.owner_user_id) %>
```